# shopify-express sequelize custom strategy

Tags: node.js, promise, shopify

I am trying to use the node module shopify-express:
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-express
using a custom strategy to store the shop tokens because the sqlstrategy doesnt work with postgres due to bad SQL statement (already have issue on github).

In the documentation they say I need to have a class as so:

```
  class Strategy {
    // shop refers to the shop's domain name
    getShop({ shop }): Promise<{accessToken: string}>
    // shop refers to the shop's domain name
    storeShop({ shop, accessToken }): Promise<{accessToken: string}>
  }
```

I made the following class:

```
class Strategy {
  // shop refers to the shop's domain name
  // Promise<{accessToken: string}>
  getShop(shopInfo) {
    const { shop } = shopInfo;
    console.log('get shop info', shopInfo)
    console.log('check domain', shop)

    return db.Shop.find({
      where: {
        shopify_domain: shop
      }
    })
    .then(foundShop => {
      return { accessToken: foundShop.access_token }
    }) 
  }
  // shop refers to the shop's domain name
  // Promise<{accessToken: string}>
  storeShop(shopInfo) {
    const { shop, accessToken } = shopInfo;
    console.log('storing store', 'shop variable', shop, 'access token variable', accessToken);
    return db.Shop.find({
      where: {
        shopify_domain: shop
      }
    })
    .then(foundShop => {
      if (foundShop) {
        foundShop.access_token = accessToken
        return foundShop.save()
        .then(foundShop => {
          return { accessToken: foundShop.access_token }
        })
      } else {
        return db.Shop.create({ shopify_domain: shop, access_token: accessToken }).then(newShop => {
          return { accessToken: newShop.access_token }
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

What is happening is it is inserting correctly but freezing.  I believe this is because I am not returning a promise?  I am still getting my head around them so not sure if I am doing it correctly or not.

IF IT HELPS:
this is the shopInfo variable on the storeShop method:

```
{ 
    accessToken: 'f444ca7789e9bcfb0fb2dc6026a79ece',
    shop: 'jldesigndevstore.myshopify.com'
}
(err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(' Error storing shop access token', err);
    }

    if (request.session) {
      request.session.accessToken = accessToken;
      request.session.shop = shop;
    } else {
      console.warn('Session not present on request, please install a session middleware.');
    }

    afterAuth(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Your `class Strategy` certainly appears to implement the prescribed interface. Both methods return a promise. By (temporarily) chaining `.catch()` to each of the promise chains, eg `db.Shop.find(...).then(...).catch(...)` you can log any errors that might arise. Don't forget to re-throw errors from the catch handlers.

Answer (score 2):

So turns out the documentation was incorrect.  Went into the node_module and saw the Memory strategy was different.  This is the Class that worked using Sequelize:

```
class SequelizeStrategy {
  async getShop({ shop }) {
    let foundShop = await db.Shop.find({
      where: {
        shopify_domain: shop
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('get shop error', err)
    })

    return done(null, {accessToken: foundShop.access_token});
  }
  async storeShop({ shop, accessToken }, done) {
    let storedShop = await db.Shop.find({
      where: {
        shopify_domain: shop
      }
    })
    .then(foundShop => {
      if (foundShop) {
        foundShop.access_token = accessToken
        foundShop.save()
        return foundShop;
      } else {
        return db.Shop.create({ shopify_domain: shop, access_token: accessToken })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('store shop error happened', err);
      return done(err);
    })
    return done(null, accessToken);
  }
}
```